# IllegalStateException: database already closed (using ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-cursoradapter, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm stumped as to what is causing this error, as I have made sure that I am closing my database adapter properly (at least I think I am). Here's what LogCat's saying (the tag for all of them is AndroidRuntime):

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.acedit.assignamo/databases/data.db (conn# 0) already closed
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2082)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:413)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:400)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:147)
>       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:178)
>       at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:225)
>       at android.widget.AbsListView.onSaveInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1569)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:9868)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2310)
>       at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(AdapterView.java:770)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2296)
>       at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:9851)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:1561)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:962)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1233)
>       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:620)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1539)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1422)
>       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10406)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
>       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
>       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
>       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
>       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
>       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:875)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My code:

```
public Cursor fetchIncompleteAssignments(Short course) {
    DbAdapter adapter = new DbAdapter(context, null, Values.ASSIGNMENT_TABLE);
    adapter.open();

    Cursor r;
    if (course == null) // Fetching from all courses
        r = adapter.fetchAllWhere(Values.ASSIGNMENT_LIST_FETCH, Values.ASSIGNMENT_KEY_STATUS + "=" + 0, Values.ASSIGNMENT_KEY_DUE_DATE);
    else
        r = adapter.fetchAllWhere(Values.ASSIGNMENT_LIST_FETCH, Values.ASSIGNMENT_KEY_COURSE + "=" + course
            + " AND " + Values.ASSIGNMENT_KEY_STATUS + "=" + 0, Values.ASSIGNMENT_KEY_DUE_DATE);
    adapter.close();
    return r;
}

// Part of DbAdapter:
public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (db != null) {
        try {
            db.close();
            dbHelper.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("Close", "Error: " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else
        Log.e("Close", "Error! db \"" + DATABASE_TABLE + "\" is null.");
}
```

The `Cursor` returned from `fetchAllAssignments()` is used to populate a `ListView` through a custom `CursorAdapter`. The `ListView` is the content of a `ListFragment`, and there are multiple instances of this ListFragment displayed in each page of a ViewPager (one for showing assignments from all courses, and then a page for each of the individual courses).

Any ideas as to what is wrong? As far as I know, I'm closing my database correctly. Let me know if you need more code. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The data is pulled from the database fine, and it populates the ListView as well. I can swipe through the various pages, but it seems to crash whenever the Fragment is stopped. It will often crash when I start another Activity, but not always. It will also occasionally crash when I'm swiping through the pages, though very rarely. Here's my onPause() method for my Fragment (I don't have an onStop() or onDestroy()):

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!assignmentsCursor.isClosed()) {
        assignmentsCursor.close();
        assignmentsCursor = null;
    }
}
```

In my `onResume()` I just reload the list from the database and get a new copy of the context via `getActivity()`. Perhaps something is getting cleared (for memory purposes) and I'm not reloading it? I'm not getting any kind of NullPointerException, so this seems unlikely to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this exception actually is raised because you double close your database, not because you did not close it.

so..

in you `close()` method, replace the following line in your code:

```
if (db != null) {
```

with:

```
if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
```

Comment: Yeah, that definitely makes the most sense of all the answers. I never thought to do that though. :)

Comment: thanks @EverythingTech96 , if this solved your problem, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `DbHelper` a singleton, as described in [**this post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html).

Comment: I think that helped. It still crashes occasionally, but I think much less. Good advice anyway, thanks! :) Any other ideas?

Comment: If you've made your `DbHelper` a singleton, you shouldn't have to close it.

Comment: Do I need to close my `SQLiteDatabase` (`db`)?

Comment: And am I _ever_ going to need to close my DbHelper? (like when I stop the Activity)

Comment: It's fine to leave it open... it won't consume a significant amount of memory resources while its open and it'll be closed when the application's process is killed by the OS. This has always been my approach... and it's the best way to easily use your db across multiple activities in my opinion.

Comment: @EverythingTech96 this is the same approach that the ContentProvider uses, by the way... it creates the `DbHelper` in `ContentProvider#onCreate()` and then leaves it open for the application's entire lifecycle. The `DbHelper` is finally closed when the application exits and the process is cleaned up by the kernel.