# Sqlite isOpen() is not show in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a database and now i want to check that database is open or not. so i am using isOpen() method to do this task. But i saw that this method is not available so i am unable to use isOpen().
i was follow this link 
    [IllegalStateException: database already closed (using ViewPager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702254/illegalstateexception-database-already-closed-using-viewpager)

This is my code:-

```
mydb db = new mydbthis);
db.close(); // this method is found.
db.isOpen() // this method is not availble.
```

solve it where i can get it.

Comment: because you are not using sqlhelper for that..

Comment: plz how can i use to sqlhelper.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/. has source code download and run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydb db = new mydbthis);
```

That won't work.

Use [`openOrCreateDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler%29) directly or extend a [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

```
File dbFile = new File(getFilesDir(),"my_app.db");
SQLiteDatabse db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile,null,null);
Log.i("TEST","DB is open: " + db.isOpen() );
```

or:

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "myapp.db";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE my_table( name TEXT, age NUMBER )");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
      //--nothing for now--
    }
}
```

used from an Activity class as:

```
DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(this); 
SQLiteDatabase db = dh.getReadableDatabase();
Log.i("TEST","DB is open: " + db.isOpen() );
```

Comment: i am doing something like this:-

Comment: public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }...}

Comment: plz suggest me where and how i could use?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        Context helperContext;

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            helperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database!!!!!");
            //db.execSQL("");
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
            } else {

                //make sure your database has this table already created in it
                //this does not actually work here
                /*
                 * db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')"
                 * );
                 * db.execSQL("INSERT INTO \"android_metadata\" VALUES ('en_US')"
                 * );
                 */
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = helperContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (mDb != null)
                mDb.close();

            super.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: also refer this link http://www.stevenmcmillan.co.uk/blog/2012/java-sqlite-database-helper-class-for-android/

Comment: hi i used something like this. but some mehod didnt used. openDataBase() etc. i used to oncreate onupgrade,

Comment: that other methods are not for you.. its just extra methods for other uses.. and there is no onOpen() method. use isOpen() method in another class or activity for check if db is open or not.

Comment: i m sry, not working in other activity and class . my database version is DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

Comment: create databasehelper object like db and check db.isOpen() in another class.